# How do you use process.start() to call an external .exe

Tags: c#

```
private void LaunchLAIFOMSApplication(string pApplicationName, string pCommandLineArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                this._laifomsProcesses.Add(pApplicationName);
                pApplicationName = pApplicationName + ".exe";
                ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo();
                process.WorkingDirectory =Application.StartupPath;
                process.FileName = pApplicationName;
                process.Arguments = pCommandLineArgs;
                process.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.CreateNoWindow = false;
                Process.Start(process);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.Message + "." + Environment.NewLine + "Please contact the Systems Administrator.", "LAIFOMS Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
        }
```

Comment: And whats the issue here?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you get an exception? Also I think FileName must be an absolute path if pApplicationName + ".exe" is not in the same folder as your application.

Comment: @jayvee the issue is that at the process.start it is not launching the exe instead it catches the exception and displays and error message of "E0000: User Login Failed."

Answer (score 0):

You should give full path of the application for `process.FileName`, not only application name

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\MyApplication.exe");
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

You need to provide the full path of your application.
And if you want to close the running exe after you run the new exe, do this

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```